# LibreOffice Writer Go to page

Tags: libreoffice

Is there a `go to page` feature in LibreOffice writer so one can type a page number to go to that page?

There similar feature in MS Word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the "`Navigator`" to jump to a certain page:

1. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to open the navigator, with the cursor in the input field for the page number:

   [image: Navigator]
2. Enter the page number and hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd> - that's it.

You can toggle display of the "`Navigator`" using <kbd>F5</kbd>.